# add checking when rendering json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am developing a sample app in rails. Now, I want to check the value of boolean variable hasUser and if it is true, then only I need to pass user details to user otherwise, just need to pass only success image as JSON

My code is given below

```
hasUser = false
render json: {
   status: 'success',
   user: @user
}
```

I don't want to write two render json for two condition, instead can I add checking so that it works fine for both conditions.

**Update**

I have changed it to

```
render json: {
   status: 'success',
   user: (hasUser ? @user: nil)
}
```

If the value hasUser is false it produces a response with user having null value. I need to remove the user part from response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Gemfile

```
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
```

Create file name

## filename.json.jbuilder

```
json.status "success"
if @hasUser
    json.user @user
end
```

OR

```
hasUser = false
data = {
   status: 'success',
   user: @user
}
data.delete(:user) unless hasUser

render json: data
```

Comment: I need to remove the user field from the response if hasUser value is false

Comment: do I have to create an extra file?

Comment: yes you have to create fie with extension json.jbuilder

Comment: Yes it really worked. I opted your second answer. Thank you brother